# Warning when using sizeof-Objective C

Tags: objective-c

```
@interface requestSession : data {
  int size;
}

- (id)init
{
    size_t size = sizeof(st);
    self=[super initWithID:ID withData:(id)pData withSize:size];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}
```

Warning:Local decalration of size hides instance variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The local declaration of `size` inside of `init` hides the instance variable `size` of your class.

Like the warning said.

Rename your local `size` to `aSize` or something similar to get rid of the warning (and potential bugs that most likely won't appear in this case)

Like this:

```
- (id)init {
    size_t aSize = sizeof(st);
    self=[super initWithID:ID withData:(id)pData withSize:aSize];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: I tried with a function named set but in there also i got the same warning!

Comment: what? Simply replace `size_t size = sizeof(st);` with `size_t aSize = sizeof(st);` and then change the size in  `initWithID:withData:withSize:` to aSize.

Comment: @fluuchtpunkt:I changed the int declared inside the interface as asize and so the error.Thanks dude for fixing up the error.